# Unique indexing in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column named Material containing different numbers

```
Material
 222
 222 
 222
 223
 223
 224
 224
```

I want to give a unique incrementing index to each material:

```
Index     Material
 1        222
 2        222 
 3        222
 1        223
 2        223
 1        224
 2        224
```

Is it possible to achieve in the Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a simple case of counting how many occurrences of the current one we've already seen.

```
= COUNTIF($A$2:$A2, $A2)
```

This says *'from the 1st row to the current one, count how many times the current row's `Material` has occurred'*. Unlike the other answer, you can use the same formula for every cell in the column; there's no special case for the 1st one. Just extend the formula down as far as you need. The result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you start on the first row of Excel, write `1` in `A1`. If you start from the second row (E.g., you have a header), do not anything explicitly.

This is the formula that you should write in `A2`:

`=IF(B1=B2,A1+1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

in first cell type 1, in second cell type 2.
Highlight both cells and drag from corner, excel will guess you want ID from 1 -> how ever long you drag.

Comment: They presumably want an automated solution, not something that would require them to do this tedious process for a possibly arbitralily high number of groups...

Comment: I agree with this, but i personaly feel you should know the very basics of excel before trying automating stuff. This is just my opinion tho.